# output a rest API specific data using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-3.2

During Performance testing, I want to output a rest API request and the specific data, if the response time for the request takes over a certain amount of time. For example, say you run 100 worker searches, and 10 had response times over, say,  2 seconds. I want JMeter to output a file that lists those long worker IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have all the information in .jtl results file, the second column is `elapsed` where you have individual requests response time. So

1. [Run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode). Don't forget to specify desired results file location via [-l command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)  like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l results.jtl
   ```
2. Once your test is finished open .jtl results file (which is "normal" [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) using Microsoft Excel or equivalent (I'm using [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/)). There you should be able to sort the samples results by "elapsed" time and identify the ones which took longer than 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds)

   [image: JMeter Results]

If you need to add an arbitrary JMeter Variable to the .jtl results file to identify the samples more precisely - take a loot at [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri for the answer. Manual sorting to filter records is ok for a one time case, but i have to do this in bulk thats why i need the filtered worker Ids (which has long run time) in bulk and it will be used as a input to SqlServer for further use (automation process)

Answer (score 0):

You can add [JSR223 Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer) which will be execute after Sample and check latency (response time) if more than 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds) do something as write to file, you can take any value for JMeter variables using `vars.get("variableName")`, example:

```
latency = sampler.getLatency();
if (latency >2000) {
        log.info("Save to file " + vars.get("workerId"));
}
```